# Как правильно реализовать карту с выезжающими bottom sheet dialog и toolbar

Tags: android, coordinator-layout, bottom-sheet

Попытался сделать [подобное](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM5kz.jpg) через `CoordinatorLayout` внутри которого лежат тулбар, карта, на которой отображено примерно 200-300 элементов (кластеризованно), и `BottomSheetDialog`. По нажатию кнопки выезжает диалог (тулбар пока статичный). Проблема заключается в следующем, если список в диалоге оставить пустым, то он прекрасно открывается и все работает. Как только я установлю эти же 200-300 элементов с карты в список, приложение начинает жутко лагать и в конце концов вылетает с ошибкой, что слишком много работы в главном потоке. Я понимаю, что таким образом мой фрагмент становится сильно перегруженным, но не имею понятия как сделать по-другому.
Если сделать через `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, то я не смогу манипулировать тулбаром на фрагменте с картой, как и самой картой. Подскажите, может есть какой-то другой подход?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить разметку элементов списка на что-то простое. Например просто TextView. Если проблема исчезнет - значит дело в разметке. Если нет или не до конца - возможно у вас RecyclerView с высотой wrapContent - так он не переиспользует ячейки и жрёт память. Значит надо ему задать фиксированную высоту и проблема должна будет исчезнуть.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб высота RecyclerView как и диалога match_parent, попробовал заменить разметку на просто TextView, и действительно проблема исчезла. Но в таком случае, я не знаю, что предпринять. Текущая разметка тоже несложная: одна ImageView и три TextView. Изображения устанавливаются Glide'ом, если это важно.

Comment: Видимо в разметке проблема. Попробуйте убрать временно картинку. Если проблема исчезнет - значит в ней дело и надо в вопрос добавить код связанный с картинкой и разметку где ImageView. Если нет - покажите адаптер и разметку.